# How to create pdf from another link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I want to generate pdf from another website, because this html page are unnecessary items.
I used libraries jspdf, jquery .ajax and my code looks like this:

```
        <script src='http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js'></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/0.5.0-alpha2/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

    $('#create_pdf').on('click',function(){
    var doc = new jsPDF('p','px','a4');

    var source1 = '';
    var
        form = '', term='';
        $.ajax({
             type: "get",
             url: "clients.php",
             dataType: "html",async: false,

              data: {
                term: term
              },
              success: function( data ) {
                   source1= data ;
              }
            });
    //alert($(source1).find('.container').eq(1).html());


    doc.addHTML(source1,options,function() {
        var string = doc.output('datauristring');
        $('.preview-pane').attr('src', string);
    });
});
```

It does not work, but alert give me html positive result.

Question 2.
How can I generate a PDF to use a different css file (eg. The media = print) to add and delete items in a PDF and print. html2canvas not using media=print

Answer (score 0):

I use the PHP library [html2pdf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phphtml2pdf/). I load the HTML content and parse it, create a new HTML code (including a special CSS) and create a PDF using html2pdf.

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "lib/html2pdf/pdf_engine.php",
    method: "post",
    success: function(data) {
        window.open( "documents/" + data );
    },
    error: function( error ) {
        console.log( error );   
    }
});
```

PHP (lib/html2pdf/pdf_engine.php):

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
    // load the PDF class
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf.class.php');
    // get the print page
    $data = file-get-contents("<your url>");
    // remove line breaks
    $data = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/", " ", $data);
    // remove whitespaces
    $data = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $data);
    // do whatever ...

    // set the pdf content
    $html = "   <page backtop=\"15mm\" backbottom=\"15mm\">
                    <page_header>
                        <table style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid #000; width: 100%; padding-bottom: 10px;\">
                            <tr>
                                <td width=\"640\">Page Title</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </page_header>
                    <page_footer>
                        <table style=\"border-top: 1px solid #000; width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;\"><tr>
                        <td width=\"320\">&copy; " . date('Y') . " My Company</td>
                        <td width=\"320\" style=\"text-align: right;\">Seite [[page_cu]] of [[page_nb]]</td>
                        </tr></table>
                    </page_footer>
                    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style_pdf.css\">
                    " . $data . "                    
                </page>";


    // load the HTML2PDF class
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','de', true, 'UTF-8', array(20, 10, 20, 10));
    // create the document
    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($html);
    // send the document to the browser and force the download
    $dir = "C:/path/to/documents/"; // remember to give access
    $file_name = "some_funky_filename.pdf";
    $html2pdf->Output($dir . $file_name, 'F');

    echo $file_name;

?>
```

The PHP gives back the filename, the jQuery opens the file in a new window.